# Resolving contents of MiFare Ultralight NFC tag

Tags: ndef, tlv

I'm currently working with NFC/NDEF and I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to understand the data coming in. I have a general understanding of the NDEF standard and have looked over the MIFARE datasheet, so I'm able to pick out a few things, but there are a few bytes that are seemingly out of place and are puzzling me.

Here is the hexdump of the data on the tag, collected via `nfc-mfultralight r`:

```
00000000  04 02 2f a1 d2 11 5f 81  1d 48 00 00 e1 10 12 00  |../..._..H......|
00000010  01 03 a0 0c 34 03 1b 91  01 05 54 02 65 6e 68 69  |....4.....T.enhi|
00000020  11 01 05 54 02 65 6e 68  69 51 01 05 54 02 65 6e  |...T.enhiQ..T.en|
00000030  68 69 fe 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |hi..............|
```

I know the first 16 bytes (`04 02 2f a1 d2 11 5f 81  1d 48 00 00 e1 10 12 00`) are the NFC/MIFARE header (first 9 being the serial number/check bytes, 1 byte for internal, 2 for lock, and then final 4 are OTP bytes.)

Starting at byte 21 I can see the start of a TLV record with the Terminator TLV flag at the end (`03 1b ... fe`), indicating a record of NDEF type with length 27. This matches the length of the expected NDEF record.

However, I'm confused by bytes 16..20 (`01 03 a0 0c 34`). What are these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears these are a part of the Lock Control TLV, a part of the [NFC Type 2 Tag standard (pages 10-11)](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf).

The bytes are laid out as such:

- `0x01` - Lock Control TLV block name
- `0x03` - Length is 3 bytes
- `0xa0` - Encodes the position within the tag the lock area is at, composed of two nibbles:

  - `0b0000` - Higher 4 bits represent the number of pages, while the lower 4 bits are the number of bytes
  - `0b1100` - The number of bits used in the lock area.
- `0x0c` - Indicates size in bits of the lock area
- `0x34` - Provides number of bytes in a page and the number of bytes each dynamic lock bit is able to lock.